# How to put border bottom to react-chips in reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react and I have created a modal and used `react-chips` for showing suggestions, but I wasn't able to change the field styling the same way I changed it for the `subject` input field. I've tried styling but I'm unable to change the styling of the `react-chip`.

Here is the code:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      chips: []
    };
  }

  onChange = chips => {
    this.setState({ chips });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Modal trigger={<Button>Show Modal</Button>}>
          <Modal.Content>
            <Form>
              <strong>Email</strong>
              <Chips
                className="f_input"
                value={this.state.chips}
                onChange={this.onChange}
                suggestions={["Your", "Data", "Here"]}
              />
              <Form.Field
                transparent
                className="f_input"
                control={Input}
                label="Subject"
              />

              <TextArea placeholder="Email Format" />
            </Form>

            <Button>Send</Button>
          </Modal.Content>
        </Modal>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the Code: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-yalow-sx678

Can anyone help me in this query?

Comment: Please put  your code in your question, not in an external link.  See [mre].

Comment: @zero298 -     I apologize, I've updated code in my query could you please preview it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library [encourages styling](https://github.com/gregchamberlain/react-chips#styles) the chips using the `chipTheme` prop;

Here is for example how you can add some custom styling to the chips in the example you provided:

```
<Chips
   className="f_input"
   value={this.state.chips}
   onChange={this.onChange}
   suggestions={["Your", "Data", "Here"]}
   chipTheme={{
      chip: {
        color: "white",
        background: "blue",
        borderRadius: 20
          },
       chipRemove: {
         fontWeight: "bold",
         cursor: "pointer",
         color: "green",
         ":hover": {
            color: "yellow"
         }
       }
     }}
/>
```

**UPDATE**

In case you would like to style the chips-container and input you should use the `theme` prop.

In your case you should override the `chipsContainer` style with the following properties in order to get an underline similar to the one you have on the "subject" input :

```
 border: "none",
 borderBottom: "1px solid black",
 marginBottom: 14,
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-hooks-snr5k) is your forked sandbox with the solution.

And [here](https://github.com/gregchamberlain/react-chips/blob/HEAD/src/theme.js) is a reference to the default theme objects which you can override.

Comment: Nope i couldn't able to give border bottom similar to `subject` input field

Comment: @Sandhya - you should use the `theme` prop then. I've updated my answer and the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-hooks-snr5k).

Comment: Thank you so much for giving solution to my query. Thank you for the documentation. It's working fine :)